# Alinhar horizontalmente várias DIVs dentro de um container

Tags: css

Tenho várias `div` com `float: left` dentro de uma outra div, que é o container delas, conforme código:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box-1" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="box-3" class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Estou tentando alinhá-las horizontalmente dentro do container (conforme figura abaixo), mas não estou conseguindo.

[image: Resultado esperado]

Bem, não consigo fazer isso funcionar. Segue meu CSS e em seguida o resultado que estou conseguindo.

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    border-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 100px; height: 200px;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}

#box-1 { background-color: red; }
#box-2 { background-color: green; }
#box-3 { background-color: pink; }
```

[image: As DIVs ficam alinhadas à esquerda]

As DIVs não estão ficando alinhadas como eu supus que aconteceria ao usar `text-align: center` na container. Como conseguir o resultado esperado?

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nE53B/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obter o resultado desejado, precisei entender que elementos com `float` fogem do flow de renderização da página e se tornam elementos independentes (dentro de limitações de `position`, `margin`, `padding`, etc).

Para resolver o problema, foi preciso apenas substituir o atributo `float: left` por `display: inline-block` na classe `.box`:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    /* o resto permanece igual */
}
```

Assim, cada uma das `DIV` se torna um elemento no fluxo de texto da página (enquanto mantém seu comportamento de bloco, que permite a definição de largura e altura, por exemplo). Obtemos assim o resultado almejado e nossas `DIVs` estão alinhadas de forma centralizada em relação ao container:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nE53B/1/)

---

*O insight dessa pergunta surgiu a partir de um problema enfrentado em um site que estou criando para um cliente. Como sempre, estou compartilhando meu conhecimento (**depois de verificar se tal pergunta já não existia**) de forma a auxiliar a meus caros parceiros usuários do SOPT.*

Comment: Dica: Para adicionar suporte ao IE que não interpreta `display: inline-block`  -> Adicione também `*display: inline; *zoom: 1;`

Comment: Estou desconsiderando totalmente o IE :-)

Comment: Obrigado Tiago, você me ajudou a resolver um problema que tava me dando nos nervos, Valeu..........